# How to run a function before App start in Revel Go Web Framework

Tags: go, revel

I am using [Revel](https://revel.github.io/) for developing a Go application, I was wondering how can I run a function just before App Loads or something like that. I know [Revel](https://revel.github.io/) provides **revel.OnAppStart** but it runs only when we hit any URL. What I want is to call the function as soon as I run the command **revel run myApp** without any extra things to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from community support...**revel.OnAppStart** runs as expected...but only when the environment is PROD not on DEV...because in testing the app is only started by the proxy when there's a request.